# Pycharm does not detect installed installed packages

Tags: python, pycharm

I got a fresh installation of Python 3.6.6 and PyCharm 2018.2 Commmunity Edition.

Unfortunately PyCharm (and also a installed with Python IDLE) does not see packages installed with pip.

I’ve installed with pip some pakages: Pillow, Pyglet, Pygame, Arcade. I can see them using pip list command, but they are inviosible in PyCharm interpreter settings. PyCharm detects only setuptools and pip.

[image]

I reinstalled Python and Pycharm several times, tried to reinstall packages with pip, but nothing helps.

Comment: You probably have more than one copy of Python installed, and the `pip` you're using is for a different version/copy of Python than the one PyCharm is using. What platform are you one, what does `python --version` and `pip --version` say on the command line, what does `python -C import sys; print(sys.executable)` on the command line and running `import sys; print(sys.executable)` say inside PyCharm?

Comment: @abarnert Nope, I uninstalled all Python versions, so I have opnly the 3.6.6 version now.
python –version is confirming it: Python 3.6.6 and pip – version says: pip 18.0 from i:\programowanie\python\python3.6.6\lib\site-packages\pip (python 3.6) which is correct path to my Python installation.
PyCharm prinbts also correct path: I:\Programowanie\Python\Python3.6.6\python.exe

Comment: @Rafał Trąbski can you import the said modules on terminal?

Comment: @NipunSampath it seems that there is only a problem with Arcade package - other packages started to show up in PyCharm and are possible to be imported in terminal. Only the Arcade package does not work.
PyCharm, when I try install it, says: „Command „python setup.py egg_info” failed with error code 1".

Comment: @Rafał Trąbski How did you tried to install Arcade on pycharm? Did you try the pycharm terminal(because the arcade does not show up in the project interpreter menu)

Comment: @NipunSampath I could not import Arcade in PyCharm terminal, but 'pip install arcade’ said that arcade is installed: „Requirement already satisfied: future in i:\programowanie\python\python3.6.6\lib\site-packages (from pyglet->arcade) (0.16.0)”
I also tried to download Arcade pressing „+” in Project interpreter manager (where Arcade is not visible) and there I got an setup.py egg_info error mentioned earlier.

Comment: could you try making a separate virtual environment(or a new project) and pip install arcade there using pycharm terminal?

Comment: @NipunSampath yes, I’ve tried a new virtualenv - with the same result: Arcade module is impossible to install, produces error: „Command „python setup.py egg_info” failed with error code 1". Other packages work fine.

Comment: @RafałTrąbski try to install from source files from https://github.com/pvcraven/arcade

Comment: @NipunSampath ok, there is an interesting update:  the Arcade works fine (when my application, which is using Arcade was started, it runs perfectly fine), but PyCharm still does not see that Arcade is installed, and, for example, the autocompletion for this module does not work, and debugger stops with an error of „No module named 'arcade’”. This is strange.
I have simmilar problem in Atom IDE - application works fine, but no autocompletion for arcade module as it was not installed.

Comment: @RafałTrąbski If arcade is installed and working outside pycharm, could you try to make a new project and check the "inherit global site packages" options when you are creating it.

Answer (score 0):

I have currently no access to my dev pc, but i encountered that specific problem multiple times before.
PyCharm provides the funtionality to use multiple python interpreters (virtual interpreters provided by pycharm and the python interpreter installed on your system). Have a look at your projects python interpreter in your project settings.

Comment: Unfortunately changing virtualenvs does not help - there is no way to install Arcade module no matter what - on the system interpreter or in the virtual environment. Every time there is same error: „„Command „python setup.py egg_info” failed with error code 1".

Answer (score -1):

It is possible that you are working on an env(may be venv) that pycharm is not able to see.

In Pycharm you will have to go to Preferences->Project:  -> and then install the package there. It will then see the packages.